# No puedo imprimir reporte. Solo aparece código de consulta a base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, csv

Intento generar un reporte descargable, cuando le de en botón con name="generar_reporte" me genere la descarga. Lo único que realiza es imprimir mi consulta:

```
query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE Gang ='$grupo'"); while($filaR= $reporteCsv->fetch_assoc())
fputcsv($salida, array($filaR['username'], $filaR['Date'], $filaR['IDGame'], $filaR['Client'], $filaR['Gang'], $filaR['Intento']));
} ?>
```

Este es el código que estoy ejecutando:

```
<?
include('conexion.php');//CONEXION A LA BD

$grupo=$_POST['grupo'];


if(isset($_POST['generar_reporte']))
{
    // NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO Y CHARSET
    header('Content-Type:text/csv; charset=latin1');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Reporte.csv"');

    // SALIDA DEL ARCHIVO
    $salida=fopen('php://output', 'w');
    // ENCABEZADOS
    fputcsv($salida, array('username', 'Date', 'IDGame', 'Client', 'Gang', 'Intento'));
    // QUERY PARA CREAR EL REPORTE
    $reporteCsv=$conexion->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE Gang ='$grupo'");
    while($filaR= $reporteCsv->fetch_assoc())
        fputcsv($salida, array($filaR['username'], 
                                $filaR['Date'],
                                $filaR['IDGame'],
                                $filaR['Client'],
                                $filaR['Gang'],
                                $filaR['Intento']));

}

?>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. ¿A qué te refieres cuando dices que   *Lo único que realiza es imprimir mi consulta*? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar `'php://output'` por un archivo real y a cambiar `<?` por `<?php`